# Automatic calculation from treeview values - tkinter python

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, save, load

Please help.  I am working on a table where the user enters the beginning of working hours *Od* and end of working hours *Do*.
The number of hours spent at work should then be calculated automatically. But now it doesn't count for me and I don't know where my mistake is anymore.

[image]

---

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo,askquestion
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
import csv

# základ okna ###############################################
okno = tk.Tk()
okno.title("Evidence pracovní doby")

# menubar ###############################################
def openfile():
"""Položka "Otevřít" v menu "Soubor" """
    with open("new.csv") as myfile:
        csvread = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=",")
        for row in csvread:
            tabulka.insert("", "end", values=row)

def savefile(): 
""" Položka "Uložit" v menu "Soubor" """ 
    with open("new.csv", "w", newline="") as myfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=",")
        for row_id in tabulka.get_children():
            row = tabulka.item(row_id)["values"]
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
    showinfo("Uložení", "Uložení proběhlo v pořádku.")

def info_menu():
""" Položka "Info" v menu"""
    info_okno = tk.Toplevel()
    info_okno.title("Info")
    Label(info_okno, text="WORK TIME v0.1", font="bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we", pady=5, padx=5)
    Label(info_okno, text="Jakub Kolář\nkolarkuba@gmail.com\n2022").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="we", pady=5, padx=5)
    close_button = Button(info_okno,text = "Zavřít",command=lambda:info_okno.destroy()).grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5)

mb = Menu(okno)
file_menu = Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Otevřít poslední", command=openfile)
file_menu.add_command(label="Uložit", command=savefile)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Zavřít", command=lambda:okno.destroy())
mb.add_cascade(label="Soubor", menu=file_menu)
mb.add_command(label="Info", command=info_menu)
okno.config(menu=mb)

# Jméno ###############################################
Label(okno, text="Jméno").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5)
jmeno = Entry(okno)
jmeno.insert(10,"")
jmeno.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5)

# Součet ###############################################
Label(okno, text="Celkem hodin").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5)
h = 0 # součet všech hodin
soucet = Entry(okno, width=5)
soucet.insert(10,h)
soucet.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5)

# tabulka ###############################################
tabulka = ttk.Treeview(okno)
tabulka.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w", padx=5)
# nastavení sloupců
tabulka["columns"] = ("Datum", "Od", "Do", "Hodin", "Misto", "Poznamka")
tabulka.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO)
tabulka.column("Datum", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tabulka.column("Od", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tabulka.column("Do", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tabulka.column("Hodin", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tabulka.column("Misto", anchor=CENTER, width=150)
tabulka.column("Poznamka", anchor=CENTER, width=80)
# nastavení popisků sloupců
tabulka.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Datum",text="Datum",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Od",text="Od",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Do",text="Do",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Hodin",text="Hodin",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Misto",text="Místo",anchor=CENTER)
tabulka.heading("Poznamka",text="Poznámka",anchor=CENTER)

# data ###############################################
data = []
global count
count = 1   
for zaznam in data:      
    tabulka.insert(parent='', index="end", iid=count, text="", values=(zaznam[0], 
zaznam[1], zaznam[2], zaznam[3], zaznam[4], zaznam[5]))       
    count += 1

# Rámec vkládacích polí ###############################################
Input_frame = Frame(okno)
Input_frame.grid(row=5, column=0)
# Popisky vkládacích polí
Datum = Label(Input_frame,text="Datum")
Datum.grid(row=0,column=0)
Od = Label(Input_frame,text="Od")
Od.grid(row=0,column=1)
Do = Label(Input_frame,text="Do")
Do.grid(row=0,column=2)
Hodin = Label(Input_frame,text="")
Hodin.grid(row=0, column=3)
Misto = Label(Input_frame,text="Místo")
Misto.grid(row=0,column=4)
Poznamka = Label(Input_frame,text="Poznámka")
Poznamka.grid(row=0,column=5)
# vkládací pole
Datum_entry = DateEntry(Input_frame, width=8)
Datum_entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
Od_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=8)
Od_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
Do_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=8)
Do_entry.grid(row=1,column=2)
Hodin_entry = Entry(width=0)
Misto_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=24)
Misto_entry.grid(row=1,column=4)
Poznamka_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=15)
Poznamka_entry.grid(row=1,column=5)

# Rámec tlačítek ###############################################
Button_frame = Frame(okno)
Button_frame.grid(row=6, column=0)

def input_record():
    """ nastavení vyčítaní vkládacích polí"""
    global count
    global h
    global citac_hodin
    tabulka.insert(
    parent="",
    index="end",
    iid = count,
    text="",
    values=(
    Datum_entry.get(),
    Od_entry.get(),
    Od_entry.get(),
    Hodin_entry.get(),
    Misto_entry.get(),
    Poznamka_entry.get()))
    count += 1   
    Datum_entry.delete(0,END)
    Od_entry.delete(0,END)
    Do_entry.delete(0,END)
    Misto_entry.delete(0,END)
    Poznamka_entry.delete(0,END)
    
def delete():
    """ Smazání vybraných dat z tabulky"""
    selected_item = tabulka.selection()[0]
    tabulka.delete(selected_item)
     
# button "Vložit záznam"
butt_plus = PhotoImage(file="/home/jakub/GitHub/Work_time/program/plus.png")
Input_button = Button(Button_frame, command=input_record, image=butt_plus, 
relief="flat").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)

# button "Smazat záznam"
butt_minus = PhotoImage(file="/home/jakub/GitHub/Work_time/program/minus.png")
delete_button = Button(Button_frame, command=delete, image=butt_minus, 
relief="flat").grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)

# metoda hlavního okna mainloop, udržuje okno otevřené
okno.mainloop()
```

Comment: would be great if you provided a [mre]

Comment: There is no code as you said to calculate the hours spent at work.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments, there was no code for `working_hours` calculation in Your example.

Basically what You have to do is to track changes of `Od` and `Do` and calculate difference between them.
You can do that by passing `textvariable` into `Entry` and then `trace` any change of that variable.

For simplicity, I made an example only for full hours (no minutes) and valid hours are between 0-24. If those conditions are not met `working_hours` are set to 0. Of course You can then modify it to work with any other time format You need. I also trimmed Your example to necessary minimum.

Also, as this is Your first question. Stick with only english, especially for comments in Your code. You make it easier for others to help You.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# základ okna ###############################################
okno = tk.Tk()
okno.title("Evidence pracovní doby")

# Rámec vkládacích polí ###############################################
Input_frame = Frame(okno)
Input_frame.grid(row=2, column=10)

# Popisky vkládacích polí
Od = Label(Input_frame, text="Od")
Od.grid(row=0, column=0)
Do = Label(Input_frame, text="Do")
Do.grid(row=0, column=1)
Hodin = Label(Input_frame, text="Hodin")
Hodin.grid(row=0, column=2)

# vkládací pole
Od_var = IntVar(value=9)
Od_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=8, textvariable=Od_var)
Od_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

Do_var = IntVar(value=17)
Do_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=8, textvariable=Do_var)
Do_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

Hodin_var = IntVar(value=8)
Hodin_entry = Entry(Input_frame, width=8, textvariable=Hodin_var, state="readonly")
Hodin_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)


def count_working_hours(*args):
    global Od_var, Do_var, Hodin_var
    try:
        # Get Od and Do values (should be integer)
        od = Od_var.get()
        do = Do_var.get()
        if not (0 <= od <= 24) or not (0 <= do <= 24) or od > do:
            # invalid input: either od or do is not valid hours or od is higher than do
            raise ArithmeticError
        working_hours = do - od
    except (TclError, ArithmeticError):
        # In case of invalid input, set working hours to 0
        working_hours = 0
    finally:
        # Set working hours
        Hodin_var.set(working_hours)


# Trace Od and Do, call count_working_hours on change
Od_var.trace("w", count_working_hours)
Do_var.trace("w", count_working_hours)

# metoda hlavního okna mainloop, udržuje okno otevřené
okno.mainloop()
```